# why activeClassName property in NavLink is not working in 6.0.2 version of react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I was using the activeClassName property to add a new class to the link when it is in active state.it worked well in version 5.0.3 of react-router-dom .
but in version 6.0.2 it started showing me warning and its not working. I couldn't able to find any descriptions about this change in the documents given in react-router website .

```
 <NavLink
    className={classes.registerButton}
    activeClassName={classes.active}
    to="/auth/SignUp"
  >cart</NavLink>
```

[image of the warning which was shown in the developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYDvk.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NavLink` API changed a bit in RRDv6, there is no longer an `activeClassName` prop.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

> ```
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style"> {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => string);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

You can conditionally apply your active class via a `className` prop function.

```
<NavLink
  className={({ isActive }) => {
    const linkClasses = [classes.registerButton];
    if (isActive) linkClasses.push(classes.active);
    
    return linkClasses.join(" "); // returns "registerButton" or "registerButton active"
  }}
  to="/auth/SignUp"
>
  cart
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 4):

"activeClassName" is no longer a property of NavLink. Instead you can use either style or className to apply your "isActive".

more on their official documentations:
https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/upgrading/v5#remove-activeclassname-and-activestyle-props-from-navlink-

Comment: Link goes to 404

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/upgrading/v5#remove-activeclassname-and-activestyle-props-from-navlink-

Answer (score 0):

style can either be a React.CSSProperties object or a function that returns a style object. If the function style is used, the link’s active state is passed as a parameter. [doc](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

```
<NavLink
      to="/faq"
         style={isActive => ({
         color: isActive ? "green" : "blue"
      })}
    >
    FAQs
  </NavLink>
```